# Loud clunking noise shifting into reverse and with sudden acceleration

Tags: noise, acura

My 94 Integra has always had a loud clunk/jolt when shifting into reverse, and recently I've noticed that when I accelerate quickly (for example, at rest in an intersection for a left turn) I sometimes hear a loud clunk/click which seems to be coming from below me on the passenger side.

Any ideas as to what this could be? I want to hear opinions so I'm informed when I head to a mechanic.

Cheers

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention: AUTOMATIC transmission, front wheel drive

Comment: Is that a manual or automatic transmission? Are the back wheels powered (either RWD or AWD)?

Comment: Automatic and front-wheel drive, no real wheel power

Comment: I don't believe you have a U-joint of the kind you've read about, then. That would be on the driveshaft from the transmission to the rear differential, but if the rear wheels aren't powered, there's no driveshaft.

Comment: I see. Any ideas as to what could be the issue?

Comment: Probably not your issue, but I had this exact thing in my Opel Corsa a few years ago and it turned out to be an empty deodorant can that clanged against the passenger seat when I suddenly changed direction or velocity. It drove me crazy for a week.

Answer (score 4):

A clicking sound on acceleration especially while turning is most commonly caused by a CV (constant velocity) joint. A CV joint transmits power from the engine to the drive wheels. If you look under the car behind the front wheel you will see a black rubber cone around each end of the axle. This is the boot or cover for the CV joint. Many times the joint wears because the boot gets torn and the grease flies out and dirt and water fly in. This causes the bearings to wear, other times the boot will be intact but the joint just wears from use. Although the joints are available separately, most repairs consist of replacing the entire axle with a rebuilt axle assemble.